# how to "flatten" / "compress" a mesh in cinema 4d?

Tags: 3d-modelling, cinema-4d

I have following 3d model:

[image]
[image]

So what I want to do is to flattern that weird shape that it is flat but does not look like crap. What would you use, how would you do that?

I tried scaling it flat, which does not work since it only scales down the top most shape which looks distorted. I tried to use the Brush tool, unfortunately that also looks like crap. I tried using the taper tool or other deformation tools, unfortunately that does not work either.

What I want it to look like afterwards:

[image]

I also don’t know what to google for.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: Are you new here @tadman? What’s the matter with you? Had a bad day or what? What a bad contribution to a question…
That is why it’s tagged "modelling" & "cinema-4d". You not even provided any example where it could be a better fit…

Comment: There's nothing wrong with me. This question has absolutely nothing to do with programming and it's off-topic. [This is fully documented](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and hasn't changed in years. There's a multitude of Cinema4D-specific forums you could put this question to. Stack Overflow can't help you.